# Convert files and merge using ConvertAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms, convertapi

I am trying to convert my doc and png files to PDF and merge them using ConvertAPI,
Whenever I try to run the code snippet provided on their site it just doesn't return any file result.

The online stats on my page shows it has been converted 
[image]

This is the code I am using

```
var convertApi = new ConvertApi("<my secret key>");
convertApi.ConvertAsync(fileFormatFrom, "pdf",
    new ConvertApiFileParam(FileToConvert)
).Result.SaveFiles(MyOutputFolder);
```

I was able to get the conversion then done using WebClient's UploadFile function, but I am not sure how to achieve Merge using the same.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: its a C#  web application, for some reason the sample that they have provided (console application) seems to work fine, but it won't work on my web application

Comment: What web application do you use? ASP.NET Web Forms?

Comment: @Tomas yes its web forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in Asynchronous handling in ASP.NET Web Forms. I am posting a working solution on how to handle async methods in ASP.NET Web Forms.

First, make your Web Form asynchronous by putting `Async=true` like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" Async="true" %>
```

Next, you need to register the async method using `RegisterAsyncTask` and only after that execute the async method itself.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(ConvertAsync));
    }

    public async Task ConvertAsync()
    {
        var convertApi = new ConvertApi("<secret>");
        var convertApiResponse = await convertApi.ConvertAsync("docx", "pdf", new ConvertApiFileParam(@"C:\TestFiles\test3.docx"));
        convertApiResponse.SaveFiles(@"C:\TestFiles");
    }
```